# Which Reference should I use to resolve the Image class?

Tags: c#, image, png, itext

I adapted some code from [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images) to try to add an image to my PDF file, which I generate using iTextSharp. Here's the code:

```
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Pictures");
Image gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/OfficeUseOnlyImg.png");
doc.Add(gif);
```

The "Image" class was unrecognized, so I right-clicked to Resolve it; I was taken aback with an embarassment of riches - the four References of the Picturelypse all offered their services:

[image]

So which one should I choose? I reckon one of the iTextSharp references, but which one is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iTextSharp.tool.*` stuff is part of XML Worker, not of iTextSharp core. You need `iTextSharp.text.Image`.

The `iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Image` class is the class that maps an `<img>` tag with an `iTextSharp.text.Image` object. You shouldn't use it unless you want to tweak XML Worker.